# Does the 500 byte limit on the Google Analytics event fields apply before or after url encoding?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I just want to know if I should be checking the length of the string corresponding to any particular event field such as category, action, or label before the object gets url encoded or after. For example, the following json object has a length of 229 bytes/characters:
`{"atracks":[{"codec":"mp3","idx":1,"lang":"und"},{"codec":"ac-3","idx":2,"lang":"und"}],"duration":634,"mime":"video/mp4","vtracks":[{"codec":"avc1.640029","idx":0}],"mimeType":"video/mp4; codecs=avc1.640029, mp3","canPlay":true}`

But once url encoded it has a length of 404 bytes:
`'el=%7B%22atracks%22%3A%5B%7B%22codec%22%3A%22mp3%22%2C%22idx%22%3A1%2C%22lang%22%3A%22und%22%7D%2C%7B%22codec%22%3A%22ac-3%22%2C%22idx%22%3A2%2C%22lang%22%3A%22und%22%7D%5D%2C%22duration%22%3A634%2C%22mime%22%3A%22video%2Fmp4%22%2C%22vtracks%22%3A%5B%7B%22codec%22%3A%22avc1.640029%22%2C%22idx%22%3A0%7D%5D%2C%22mimeType%22%3A%22video%2Fmp4%3B%20codecs%3Davc1.640029%2C%20mp3%22%2C%22canPlay%22%3Atrue%7D'`